# SQL (for teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata

If I have a dataset as follows:

```
1/01/2014   a
2/01/2014   a
3/01/2014   a
4/01/2014   b
5/01/2014   b
6/01/2014   b
7/01/2014   b
8/01/2014   a
9/01/2014   a
10/01/2014  a
11/01/2014  a
12/01/2014  a
13/01/2014  a
```

How would I get output that looks like this:

```
letter  min     max
a   1/01/2014   3/01/2014
b   4/01/2014   7/01/2014
a   8/01/2014   13/01/2014
```

Comment: What if there's a gap between the dates, e.g. `6/01/2014` is missing? Do you still want to return `b   4/01/2014   7/01/2014` or `b   4/01/2014   5/01/2014` plus  `b   7/01/2014   7/01/2014`?

Comment: And what's your Teradata release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata supports the window functions.  You need to calculate a group identifier.  One method is a difference of row numbers:

```
select letter, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by letter order by date)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by letter, grp;
```